# How to open another app without "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"?

Tags: android

There are some links in my app. It will start browsable intent like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
startActivity(intent);
```

Then it will open a browser. At the same time, something is running in background and need to update UI. So I get this:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`
I know the reason about this Exception. But how to fix it? It would be better that background task can keep running. However, pausing them is also acceptable.

Comment: for updating UI from background tasks try the runonUiThread

Comment: why would you update the UI if the activity is in the background?

Comment: @eldjon If you don't click the link, updating will not be in background...

Comment: you are updating from a AsyncTask?

Comment: @eldjon I updated UI by a `AsyncTask` and another `Thread`, now I move the `Thread` in a `AsyncTask` and this Exception disappear. I think I should not use `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `AsyncTask` you really dont need `runOnUiThread()` method. `AsyncTask` provides you with everything you need. It encapsulates two methods: `preExecute()` and `postExecute()` which run on the main thread, so you can update the UI components within these methods. Even if you need to update the UI progressively `AsyncTask` handles that in `onProgressUpdate()` method which again runs on main thread. This way your code is much cleaner then inserting:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() { 
    public  void  run() { 
    } 
});
```

You can even cancel an ongoing task: `asyncTask.cancel()` for example `onPause()` method of your activity in order to avoid any unnecessary UI updates while the activity is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to do if the UI is not visible to user?? 
anyway,

for updating UI from background tasks try the runonUiThread

```
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() { 
        public  void  run() { 
            //access UI here
        } 
    });
```

http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?s=runOnUiThread

Comment: I just want updating to be done when they close the browser and back to my app, or it can pause when they leave and start when they back.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback used to update the UI, check if the activity is paused or stopped, and don't perform the UI update logic. You can use a flag `isForeground` which you set true in onResume() and false in onStop().

Alternatively, I found that you can avoid the exception if you use `commitAllowingStateLoss` when committing fragment transactions.